# New view in xml(layout) file cant be created(java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field tv of type I)

Tags: android, view

I have a project which uses two modules(libraries), I created some activity and its respective layout file in one of my library, I can't seem to add new views in that layout (Textview, Imageview etc). Here is the logcat output.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field tv of type I in class Lcom/camera/sushant/opencamera/R$id; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.camera.sushant.opencamera.R$id' appears in /data/app/com.streetspotr.streetspotr.staging-1/base.apk)
    at com.camera.opencamera.MediaPreview.onCreate(MediaPreview.java:89)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Apparently what was happening, I had layout with same name in my app module and my library module. So when packaging the application it was always taking the layout from my app module not library module. So I had to delete the layout in my app module and everything worked fine.

Comment: Yeah, this was the case for me too. I also tried using full namespace for resource like `com.company.product.module.R.layout.layout_name`, and still I got the same error. I ended up deleting the layout with the same name from my app's layout folder.

Answer (score 0):

Moving a resource from your project to a library can lead to this problem as well. If you did this, cleaning the project solves the problem...

Comment: But cleaning the library project or the project in which i am using library?