# NoSuchFieldError: No static field listView1 of type I in class Lcom/disdemo/R$id; or its superclasses

Tags: android

I have module1 (in Android Studio) with listView1 in `activity_main.xml` (present in res of the module1). The MainActivity of this module is being launched from another module2 in the same Android Studio project.

I have tried deleting the module1 and again creating a new one with same res and java files. Still I am getting the same issue.

Comment: I have added the module in settings.gradle and build.gradle

Comment: I had activity_main.xml layout in one of my other modules as well, so I was getting this NoSuchField error. I rename the layout in one of my modules and it worked.

Comment: My case was a little different, as I had moved a string resource from one module to another. In my case I just had to click Build > Clean in Android Studio to fix the issue.

Comment: Yes, for you it wasn't an issue of duplicate resource file, so clean -> build worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New view in xml(layout) file cant be created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321529/new-view-in-xmllayout-file-cant-be-created)

Comment: I've also encountered this error in localized resource directories when I forgot to add the un-qualified value; e.g. adding `res/raw-fr/test.json` but forgetting `res/raw/test.json`

Answer (score 214):

I think you have layout in both library and module with same name or inflating multiple xml layout with duplicate resource id.

Comment: Yes, exactly that was the case. I figured it out soon but sad thing is a lot of time was wasted on this since, the error message was not intuitive enough. Android Studio should start logging more comprehensive error messages.

Comment: **sounds good!** now you should mark it as approved so this can help another one to resolve this type of issue.

Comment: If you use AS's refactor-rename, it renames all occurrences of e.g. `activity_main.xml`, better do it by hand.

Comment: I was getting this error due to two layouts with same name in app and module. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I had same issue, but in my case the reason was same package name in `AndroidManifest.xml` for both the app and the lib.

Comment: another team was working on a different module we both left the default  nav_graph.xml unchanged. 
we had no clue where this error was coming from.
Thank you

Comment: for me, I had to Clean the project: AndroidStudio > Build > Clean Project

Answer (score 34):

In both modules, you have an `activity_main.xml`. Please rename one file.

Update:
What @kundan kamal wants to express is, you have a layout file in both modules with a similar name.

Answer (score 8):

you have use multiple module and give same name of any xml layout then give this error so please rename your xml layout.

Answer (score 2):

In my case identifiers were different. I pressed `Build > Rebuild Project`. This is because I divided `res/layout` into subfolders, and AS stopped to notice XML changes. See [Rebuild required after changing xml layout files in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317822/rebuild-required-after-changing-xml-layout-files-in-android-studio) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Make me correct If I am not wrong...
I think you have the same name of your library and module in your project so you have to rename one of them then its work fine

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error happened once to me, but with a `string` resource. I had the string configured in a translation file, but not in the default string resource file, so this produced the crash.

Answer (score 0):

For me proguard rules worked. I had two level proguard. First in my dependency and then in my app. Had to do this in my dependency gradle.

Preserve R.*.* things.

```
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your xml is in same module/package/project where you have written the logic to show the code.
In my case my xml was in different module which was not accessible.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue when using `viewBinding`. Class name was `SearchViewHolder` and layout resourse name was `search_view_holder`. That caused confusion and crash.