# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError caused by 3rd Party module

Tags: java, android

I've integrated a third party library in my Android project.
The library is provided in form of an .aar file.

Implementation of it, is a simple one-liner that creates a customdialog in my mainactiviy.

But whenever it tries to create the dialog my app will crash with

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: de.thirdparty.lib.R$id.neverParticipateButton
  at de.thirdparty.lib.views.DialogBuilder.buildView(DialogBuilder.java:97)
```

I have implemented the library in a new empty android project and it worked as planned. So it seems like there's a conflict with my project.

I've read in a different post ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440321/nosuchfielderror-no-static-field-listview1-of-type-i-in-class-lcom-disdemo-rid)), that it can be caused when project and library accidentally use the same name for a layout. But when i inspect the library's code in my build folder, I can't find any layouts that use the same names. Also not ids or drawables.

Does somebody have an idea what else can cause this Error, or advice how to debug?

Kind Regards 
Christian

Comment: You should check version of third library. May be that method has removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was that another 3rd Party library that was already integrated in my app had the same layout name as the new one... Nothing much i could do here but to inform the devs of the libs to use prefixes.