# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field CircleImageView of type [I in class Lcom/xxx/R$styleable or its superclasses

Tags: java, android

load a plugin apk happens error
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field CircleImageView of type [I in class Lcom/xxx/R$styleable; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.xxx.R$styleable' appears in /data/app/~~vFqnN9P5eHbShcIew1i9TA==/com.xxx-fau_-7LnbtKd-imOM8llyg==/base.apk)

attrs

```
<declare-styleable name="CircleImageView">
    <attr name="civ_border_width" format="dimension" />`enter code here`
    <attr name="civ_border_color" format="color" />
    <attr name="civ_border_overlay" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="civ_circle_background_color" format="color" />
</declare-styleable>


  public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircleImageView, defStyle, 0);

    mBorderWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_width, DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH);
    mBorderColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_color, DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
    mBorderOverlay = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_overlay, DEFAULT_BORDER_OVERLAY);
    mCircleBackgroundColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_circle_background_color, DEFAULT_CIRCLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR);

    a.recycle();

    init();
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `CircleImageView` class code?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440321/nosuchfielderror-no-static-field-listview1-of-type-i-in-class-lcom-disdemo-rid

Comment: @LucaPizzini  just like follow, is  common custom view