# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field MapAttrs_liteMode of type I in class Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to run application with Google Maps v2, but it throws me error and I have no idea why:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field MapAttrs_liteMode of type I in class Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.R$styleable' appears in /data/app/com.example.OKM-1/base.apk)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2169)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:381)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
        at com.example.OKM.presentation.view.MainMapActivity.onCreate(MainMapActivity.java:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

I have Google Play Services (Rev. 25) and Support v4 added to my project.
Here is my code:

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.OKM">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>

<permission
        android:name="com.example.OKM.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.OKM.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:allowBackup="true">
    <activity android:name=".presentation.view.MainMapActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/mapsKey" />
</application>


</manifest>
```

... and activity:

```
package com.example.OKM.presentation.view;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.example.OKM.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.example.OKM.presentation.presenter.MainMapPresenter;

public class MainMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{
private MainMapPresenter mainMapPresenter;
private SupportMapFragment map;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_map_activity);

    if(map == null){
        map = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map.getMapAsync(this);
    }



    mainMapPresenter = new MainMapPresenter(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

}
}
```

Have you any idea what may by wrong? If you want more info notify me please

Comment: Just rename your local style name to precise rename this style MapAttrs_liteMode


Another developer faced problem in creating same file name as in library


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28917157/2700586
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440321/nosuchfielderror-no-static-field-listview1-of-type-i-in-class-lcom-disdemo-rid#comment47090977_29440321

Answer (score 0):

I think you have layout in both library and module with same name or
inflating multiple xml layout with duplicate resource id.

**Find map_attrs in play-services-lib and replace with this code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <declare-styleable name="MapAttrs">
    <attr name="mapType" format="enum">
      <enum name="none" value="0"/>
      <enum name="normal" value="1"/>
      <enum name="satellite" value="2"/>
      <enum name="terrain" value="3"/>
      <enum name="hybrid" value="4"/>



    </attr>
    <attr name="cameraBearing" format="float"/>
    <attr name="cameraTargetLat" format="float"/>
    <attr name="cameraTargetLng" format="float"/>
    <attr name="cameraTilt" format="float"/>
    <attr name="cameraZoom" format="float"/>
    <attr name="liteMode" format="boolean"/>



    <attr name="uiCompass" format="boolean"/>
    <attr name="uiRotateGestures" format="boolean"/>
    <attr name="uiScrollGestures" format="boolean"/>
    <attr name="uiTiltGestures" format="boolean"/>
    <attr name="uiZoomControls" format="boolean"/>
    <attr name="uiZoomGestures" format="boolean"/>
    <attr name="useViewLifecycle" format="boolean"/>
    <attr name="zOrderOnTop" format="boolean"/>
    <attr name="uiMapToolbar" format="boolean"/>
    <attr name="ambientEnabled" format="boolean"/>
  </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating your Google Repository to version 15 via the SDK Manager should resolve the issues and eliminate the needs for the workarounds. A project clean is required.

Android SDK

This is also mentioned in [issue 7432](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7432).